# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while using caffeine

Tags: java, maven, bukkit, caffeine-cache

I was making a Minecraft plugin (with maven) and was going to use caffeine for a cache, but when I ran my server with the plugin jar, I got the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/Caffeine
```

I am updated to the latest version of caffeine (v3.0.3) and maven (v3.8.1). I honestly have nothing else to show other than that error. I only imported the following caffeine packages:

```java
import com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Cache;
import com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine
```

pom.xml (no repo)

```xml
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
 <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
 <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

server log: https://pastebin.com/zMzx37dk

Comment: The caffeine jar file needs to be distributed to your server along with your plugin, or it needs to be packaged within your jar.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the cause is that the library is not included in the jar file.
Try building by adding code like the following to `plugins` in pom.xml.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```